# CloudFormation Custom Name Resource requires replacing while i can't find the resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I have just tried to update a DynamoDB table in a CloudFormation stack. However, I get the error : 'CloudFormation cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing.' which is perfectly OK and I'll fix this later on. 
What  I don't understand is that I cannot find the table in he DynamoDB listTables command. Anyone has encountered this before ? 
Note that this table existed before the attempt...

Comment: Sometimes when you don't find things in AWS you may have the wrong region selected. Other than that, "Replacement" update does delete the old resource and creates a new one after that, maybe the first part did go through.